# I have not valid laravel pagination url in routes

Tags: laravel

in my Laravel 8 /  tailwindcss 2 app
I use pagination and failed to create valid page url with routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    // http://local-tads-back.com/admin/categories/page?=3
    Route::get('categories/page?=/{page?}', [CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('CategoriesFilter');

    Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class);   // app/Http/Controllers/Admin/CategoryController.php
    ...
```

I got error :

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController::show does not exist.
```

I do not have show method and try to set page condition before Route::resource ?
Is my condition invalid ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```php
 Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class)->except(['show'])
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

Comment: I tryed and got error : The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT, PATCH, DELETE.   why?

Comment: it's means that urlis not support get method

Comment: Not sure which way is valid ?

Comment: Working pagination in my listing. When on url "admin/categories/page?=3" in controller I got $page == 3. Url can be different, like "admin/categories/pag/3"